# Convolution 1D for time series analysis explanation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a TensorFlow model to analyze sounds with a 1D convnet. each of my samples is structured as 128 mel filters and 431 timesteps. Therefore the shape of my data is `(128, 431)`.

How should I feed my data into the convolutional layer? With mel filter first or timestep first?
Mel first would be:

```
from tensorflow import keras
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(128, 431))
out = keras.layers(10, 10)(input)
```

Timesteps first would be:

```
from tensorflow import keras
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(431, 128))
out = keras.layers(10, 10)(input)
```

My intuition is saying that I should put my timesteps first, therefore I should transpose my data because the convolutions are done along the horizontal axes of the matrix, but I can't find anything that confirms my intuition.

Comment: You can consider each timestep as a pixel. So, you have an image with 431 pixels lined-up. Consider the number of mel-filters as the number of channels in this image. The kernel would run along this image in case of `Conv1D` ( as the name suggests, it runs along a single dimension ).

Comment: Convolutional layers have a `data_format` argument, which can be `channels_first` or `channels_last`. You should order your data such that it fits whatever you are using in the layers.